# Get access to values from different interface

Tags: objective-c

I have an interface called `A` that's saves some values to `float` type:

I declare in `.h` file:

```
float x,y;
```

and in the `.m` files initilizing them:
x=56.4;
y=666.3;

How can i access those values from another interface? I want to do something like this:

```
float MyX = A.x;
float myY = A.y;
```

Comment: Use [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed use properties. Properties 'exposes' your variables and generates a pair of getter/setter methods automatically. In your .h file you can declare the following:

```
@property float x;
@property float y;
```

And you should synthesize then in your .m file:

```
@synthesize x;
@synthesize y;
```

Then you can access the variables the way you want it ;)